# Merge PDF files from multiple folders with same filename

Tags: windows, pdf, pdftk

I am looking to merge PDF files from two separate folders into a third folder, based on file name.

Directory structure:

```
FOLDER_1 = File set #1.
FOLDER_2 = File set #2.
MERGED_PDFS = Output of merged files.
```

FOLDER_1 contains a set of PDF files which could be named with any combination of letters, numbers and allowed symbols.

FOLDER_2 contains a set of PDFs with the exact same names as FOLDER_1. The data on these sheets is different. The files from FOLDER_2 need to be inserted into the files from FOLDER_1, at the end of the file.

The output of this merged file will be placed in the MERGED_PDFs folder, retaining the name used to match the files in FOLDER_1 and FOLDER_2.

Example:

```
FOLDER_1: R000135322.PDF
FOLDER_2: R000135322.PDF
MERGED_PDFS: R000135322.PDF
(MERGED_PDFS contains a merged PDF from FOLDER_1 & FOLDER_2, with the PDF from FOLDER_2 being placed at the end of the PDF in FOLDER_1.
```

I saw some similar examples of this being done with PDFtk, but unsure how to edit to get my expected output.

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: You haven't explained a whole lot, just that you want some files *somehow* merged. It's unclear what your understanding of *"merging"* is, which programming language you wish to use, and what you are having difficulty with. This question is probably off-topic (see [help/on-topic]) for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You grossly underestimate the complexity of the PDF file format. PDFs are structured storage, and merging can be done in a million different ways, e.g. appending text immediately after existing text, or moving it to a new page. References may need to be merged into a single section, same goes for footnotes. The table of contents may need to be updated, or a cross reference of images and tables. What about conflicting `/Author`, `/Producer` or `/Title` metadata?

Comment: This should make it crystal clear: Open a PDF in Acrobat. Click Tools> Insert from File. When the options dialog pops up, choose Location: After and Page:Last. This will insert a PDF after the last page of the current document. Ignoring TOC, References, Footnotes and metadata. This is the action I am trying to simulate, based on matching file names.

Comment: So there really is more than *"somehow merge PDF files"*, as you kept insisting. Stack Overflow is for developers. We like unambiguous specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Install FolderMill
2. Specify the Incoming folder and the Output folder for FolderMill on your PC
3. Since you mention that files in FOLDER_1 and files in FOLDER_2 have the same filenames, just add "Convert to PDF" action and select Multipage: "Append pages to existing document" in the options.
4. Click Apply changes
5. Start FolderMill by pressing the Play button.
6. Grab the files from FOLDER_1 and put them into the Incoming folder
7. Grab the files from FOLDER_2 and do the same.
8. Receive the merged PDFs from the Output folder

If the you are not sure if all the corresponding files have the same filenames, you may also need to use the "Rename" action.

FYI, we have a detailed [step-by-step guide](https://www.foldermill.com/solutions/append-pages-to-multipage-pdf-or-tiff) how to do it (with screenshots).

You are welcome :)